# findroot multiple variables

Tags: equation-solving

I have an equation `811*a + 741*b + 1025*c + 752*d = 94508.16372`

How can I find the possible roots of a b c and d in specific scopes?
I tried `FindRoot`, it doesn't work since it's not a system of equations.

Comment: For "specific scopes" include constraints as part of the system of equalities or **inequalities** given to `Reduce` or `Solve` or `NSolve`. Or use `FindInstance` to get some example solutions. For example, `FindInstance[811 a + 741 b + 1025 c + 752 d == 94508.16372, {a, b, c, d}, Reals, 5]` Also, `FindInstance` can take constraints.

Comment: Thanks for help Bob

Answer (score 3):

As you have 1 equation but 4 variables, the answer will have 3 free variables. The calculation can easily be done by hand. But if, for some reason, you want to use MMA, you may e.g. solve for `d` as a function of the variables `a,b,c` (assuming you want real solutions):

```
eq = 811 a + 741 b + 1025 c + 752 d == 94508.16372;
Solve[eq, {d}, Reals]
(* {{d -> 125.676 - 1.07846 a - 0.985372 b - 1.36303 c}} *)
```

Or you may e.g. use `Reduce` to solve for `a` as a function of the variables `b,c,d`

```
Reduce[eq, {a}, Reals]
(* a == 116.533 - 0.913687 b - 1.26387 c - 0.92725 d *)
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. But what I want is to find the numerical solutions for all the variables. Is that possible?

Comment: There is an infinity of solutions, parametrized by 3 variables. If you want one unique solution, you must specify 3 more equations to pick out the one you want